# Trying to solve an array related question of avoiding obstacles from codesignal

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this stage in codesignal wherein the function has to return how many steps to avoid the obstacles starting from 0, and the size of the jump has to remain constant all throughout the array. e.g [5,3,6,7,9] should give an output of 4, as it starts from 0, lands at 4, jumps again, and lands at 8, and by jumping 4 places, it avoids every element in the given array.
I've looked at the solutions to try and understand how to solve this more efficiently and I came across this solution in particular

```
def avoidObstacles(inputArray):
    c = 2
    while True:
        if sorted([i%c for i in inputArray])[0]>0:
            return c
        c += 1
```

I understood everything in the solution except for 1 part: \

what exactly does the *[0]* after the sorted array do in this code? \

`if sorted([i%c for i in inputArray])[0] > 0`

Comment: sorted returns a list. the IF statement is accessing the first element of the sorted list and checking if it's bigger than 0

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

**`sorted`** returns a list with the elements sorted. Here the code means **`If the first element of the sorted list is greater than 0`**

Comment: Thank you for this!